# Using facets with missing filters in ElasticSearch and Tire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I am trying to use facets with a search query that includes a missing filter and it does not seem to take into account the records that will be filtered away with the missing filter.

In the Rails app:

```
@items = Item.search(per_page: 100, page: params[:page], load: true) do |search|
  search.query do |query|
    query.boolean do |boolean|
      boolean.must { |must| must.string params[:q], default_operator: "AND" }
      boolean.must { |must| must.term :project_id, @project.id }
    end
    query.filtered do
      filter :missing , :field =>  :user_id
    end
  end
  search.facet('tags') do
    terms :tag
  end
end
```

generates the request:

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/items/user_story/item?load=true&size=100&pretty' -d '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*",
            "default_operator": "AND"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "project_id": {
              "term": 132
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "missing": {
              "field": "user_id"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "facets": {
    "tags": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "tag",
        "size": 10,
        "all_terms": false
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 100
}'
```

which has `nil` for facets.

If I move the missing filter out to search.filter

```
@items = Item.search(per_page: 100, page: params[:page], load: true) do |search|
  search.query do |query|
    query.boolean do |boolean|
      boolean.must { |must| must.string params[:q], default_operator: "AND" }
      boolean.must { |must| must.term :project_id, @project.id }
    end
  end
  search.filter(:missing, :field => 'user_id' )
  search.facet('tags') do
    terms :tag
  end
end
```

...it makes the request:

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/user_stories/user_story/_search?load=true&size=100&pretty' -d '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*",
            "default_operator": "AND"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "project_id": {
              "term": 132
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "facets": {
    "tags": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "tag",
        "size": 10,
        "all_terms": false
      }
    }
  },
  "filter": {
    "missing": {
      "field": "user_id"
    }
  },
  "size": 100
}'
```

which does get the facets but they do not take into account the filtered records.

Is there another way I should be writing my query so I can get facets that also take into account the missing filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly, you're hitting the problem where facets are computed from results limited by the query, not by the top-level `filter` element. Also, the first query doesn't look right to me.

I'd rewrite the request like this:

```
require 'tire'

params = {:q => 'foo'}

s = Tire.search do |search|
  search.query do |search_query|
    search_query.filtered do |f|

      # Queries
      f.query do |q|
        q.string params[:q], default_operator: "AND"
      end

      # Filters
      f.filter :missing , :field => :user_id
      f.filter :term,     :project_id => '123'
    end
  end
  search.facet('tags') do
    terms :tag
  end
end

puts s.to_curl
```

Basically, we use the `filtered` query as the main query, getting rid of the boolean query, and using `filter` for maximum efficiency (missing and term).

Of course, if you'd need to perform more queries, you could use `q.boolean` instead of `q.string`.

Lastly, the `string` query (ie. the Lucene query string query) is usually suboptimal choice for regular searches, since it exponses the whole "special Lucene syntax" to the user, and is error prone. The `match` query is usually a much better choice.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll try this out later today.